# How can I replace a value on an Access 2007 report with an image?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a colour field in the table I am reporting from. I am intending to replace this text on a report with a small square of colour based on the word.

I have been digging around in Access for days trying to do this and cant seem to find any options in VBA nor the Properties pane.

Updates: Thanks to Tom for pointing me in the right direction, so far I have this sort of working, decided to use a textbox instead of a rectangle as then I can still have the colour text inside. So using the Report_Current event I wrote a huge "Select Case Report_rptSRSearch.Colour" to handle this.

Using the Report_Current event does not seem to give the exact required functionality however. It will do exactly what I want except only when the user physically clicks the record on the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally figured this out and you have to use the Detail_Paint method. Duh ;)

Answer (score 2):

Not testing this, so my syntax may be off slightly.

Create your square on your form. In this example we'll call it square1.
On the Form_Current event (VBA), check the value of the colour field, and using a Select Case statement, set the background colour of square1.

Comment: I do not see any reason to have it unbound. If the colour is RGB, and the control is called `Colour`, you could say `Me.Colour.BackColor = Me.Colour`:`Me.Colour.ForeColor = Me.Colour` If the colour is web style, it is easy enough to convert the colour to work in MS Access.

Comment: I need this in a report though, cant find a Current event for reports.

Edit: Found the event (was only looking at detail) tinkering with your idea now ;)

Comment: I have tried 'Select Case Report_rptSRSearch.Colour' but this seems to always return Null. If I click on a record then it will run the code but I want this to happen for each record in the report before it is shown to the user.

Comment: Use the Detail_Print event. Here's an example:

Private Sub Detail_Paint()
   Select Case LCase(Me.square1)
      Case "apple"
         Me.square1.BackColor = vbRed
      Case "pear"
         Me.square1.BackColor = vbGreen
      Case "banana"
         Me.square1.BackColor = vbYellow
   End Select
End Sub

square1 is the field name. I did an LCase on the field value because the Select statement is case sensitive. So without converting it to lower case, apple will not match Apple.

Comment: Cheers Detail_Print was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the note on select I usually go UCase as they are constants in my mind ;) I am very familiar with VB6 its just a matter of finding the new things!

Comment: Turns out not so exactly what I was looking for, back to the drawing board!